# Block wp-admin.php for non admin users in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, redirect

I want to use the user structure in wordpress for a website, but when a user logs in using the traditional wp-login.php, if the user is not an admin, it enters wp-admin.php with it's profile and a dashboard.

I don't want that. I would like that, after a successfull login, all non admin users to be redirected by the main page, and every time a non admin user tries to enter in wp-admin.php to redirect them as well.

Is there a plugin for that? Thanks!

Comment: I can't help it: this is the single best user name and gravatar I know on SO :) ... although I strongly suspect you are cheating poor MS-DOS right now in order to post here :)

Comment: .. - What do you want the non-admin user to be able to do once they have logged in such that you need them to be logged in? Also, you might want to post this over at SO's sister site where lots of WordPress enthusiasts are available to help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Pekka, there's Lynx for dos! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I haven't used it, but this looks promising: [Hiding the WordPress Dashboard for Non-Admin Users](http://bavotasan.com/tutorials/hiding-the-wordpress-dashboard-for-non-admin-users/)

Comment: Hum, it seens interesting. It seems it has exactly what I want in a comment: I simplified it like this to send non-admin to homepage:


add_action('admin_menu', 'redirect_dashboard');
function redirect_dashboard(){
if( !current_user_can('level_10') ){
if( preg_match('#wp-admin/?(index.php)?$#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && ('index.php' != $menu[$page][2]) )
wp_redirect(get_bloginfo('url'));
}
}